# Is there a way to use prevent default and still receive post requests?

Tags: javascript, validation, http-post, preventdefault

I am trying to properly validate form-data on my backend and still be able to have a nice user experience with form validation on my front end which is written in Javascript. I have all the form validation done on the front end, in order to get the effect we want we used `e.PreventDefault()` on our submit button so we can display any input errors to the user without a reload. The issue is when you actually fill out the form now and click submit there is no POST request being sent to the server because of the preventDefault.

Removing the line completely seemed to fix the problem of our server not receiving post requests but that creates the issue of the front end form validation being completely pointless because the error messages aren't displayed because of the refreshed page.

Javascript Front End Validation:

```
let btn = document.querySelector('.btn')

btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault() // <---- THIS IS THE ISSUE

    let firstName = document.querySelector('.firstName').value
    let lastName = document.querySelector('.lastName').value
    let email = document.querySelector('.email').value
    let createPassword = document.querySelector('.createPassword').value
    let verifyPassword = document.querySelector('.verifyPassword').value

    let firstNameSubmit = false
    let lasttNameSubmit = false
    let emailSubmit = false
    let createPasswordSubmit = false
    let verifyPasswordSubmit = false


    if (/^\s+$/.test(firstName) || firstName == null || firstName == '') {
        document.querySelector('.firstNameError').innerHTML = 'First Name is a required field'
        document.querySelector('.firstName').style.borderBottom = '1px solid red'

    } else if (!/^\s+$/.test(firstName) || firstName !== null || firstName !== '') {
        document.querySelector('.firstNameError').innerHTML = null
        document.querySelector('.firstName').style.borderBottom = '1px solid #2ecc71'
        firstNameSubmit = true

    } if (/^\s+$/.test(lastName) || lastName == null || lastName == '') {
        document.querySelector('.lastNameError').innerHTML = 'Last Name is a required field'
        document.querySelector('.lastName').style.borderBottom = '1px solid red'

    } else if (!/^\s+$/.test(lastName) || lastName !== null || lastName !== '') {
        document.querySelector('.lastNameError').innerHTML = null
        document.querySelector('.lastName').style.borderBottom = '1px solid #2ecc71'
        lasttNameSubmit = true

    } if (!/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email)) {
        document.querySelector('.emailError').innerHTML = 'Please enter a valid email'
        document.querySelector('.email').style.borderBottom = '1px solid red'

    } else if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email)) {
        document.querySelector('.emailError').innerHTML = null
        document.querySelector('.email').style.borderBottom = '1px solid #2ecc71'
        emailSubmit = true

    } if (/^\s+$/.test(createPassword) || createPassword == null || createPassword == '' || createPassword.length < 6) {
        document.querySelector('.createPasswordError').innerHTML = 'Password must be longer than 6 characters'
        document.querySelector('.createPassword').style.borderBottom = '1px solid red'

    } else if (!/^\s+$/.test(createPassword) || createPassword !== null || createPassword !== '' || createPassword.length >= 6) {
        document.querySelector('.createPasswordError').innerHTML = null
        document.querySelector('.createPassword').style.borderBottom = '1px solid #2ecc71'
        createPasswordSubmit = true

    } if (!createPasswordSubmit) {
        document.querySelector('.verifyPasswordError').innerHTML = `Passwords don't match`
        document.querySelector('.verifyPassword').style.borderBottom = '1px solid red'

    } else if (verifyPassword == createPassword){
        document.querySelector('.verifyPasswordError').innerHTML = null
        document.querySelector('.verifyPassword').style.borderBottom = '1px solid #2ecc71'
        verifyPasswordSubmit = true
    }
```

Go Backend Halders:

```golang
http.HandleFunc("/signup", signupHandler) // inside func main()


func signupHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method != "POST" {
        tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "signup.html", nil)
        fmt.Printf("METHOD: %s | URL: %v\n", r.Method, r.URL)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("METHOD: %s | URL: %v\n", r.Method, r.URL)

    r.ParseForm()
    f := r.PostFormValue("fname")
    l := r.PostFormValue("lname")
    e := r.PostFormValue("email")
    pw := r.PostFormValue("pass")

    hash, err := helper.HashPassword(pw) 
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Hashing Error")
    }

    fmt.Println("LoginValues")
    fmt.Printf("%s\n, %s\n, %s\n, %s\n", f, l, e, hash)
}
```

Signup Template HTML:

```html
<form action="/signup" method="post">
     <h3>First Name</h3>
     <input name="fname" type="text" class="firstName">
     <p class="firstNameError"></p>
     <h3>Last Name</h3>
     <input name="lname" type="text" class="lastName">
     <p class="lastNameError"></p>
     <h3>Email</h3>
     <input name="email" type="text" class="email">
     <p class="emailError"></p>
     <h3>Create Password</h3>
     <input name="pass" type="password" class="createPassword">
     <p class="createPasswordError"></p>
     <h3>Verify Password</h3>
     <input type="password" class="verifyPassword">
     <p class="verifyPasswordError"></p>
     <button class="btn" type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

I just want to know if there's a work around for front end with back end form validation either with preventDefault or if I need to approach the concept a different way if so how? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of calling `preventDefault` before checking for errors, why not call it after front end validation, but only if an error has been detected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's a type="submit" button, event.preventDefault() is preventing the "submit" event from firing (and the "submit" event is what sends the data to the backend).

Instead of listening for a "click" event on the button, I think it is better listen to a "submit" event on the form.  It will be triggered on the form when you click a button with type="submit."

The form will now be the event's target.

```
let form = document.getElementById('my-form')
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {})
```

So, at the beginning of your function, you should be able to prevent the submit action by  calling

```
event.preventDefault();
```

But, you can also store the form to a local variable, since that is the element that the submit event is triggering on:

```
let form = event.target
```

Then, if there are no errors, you can trigger the submit on the form at the end of your function:

```
form.submit()
```

all together:

```
let form = document.getElementById('my-form')
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault()
   let form = event.target
   let errors = false;
   //do all of the error checking here, if there's an error, set errors to true
   if(!errors) {
       form.submit()
   }
})
```

(There might be a better way, but that's what I could think of off the top of my head.  Also, it might be easier to get all of the data values by adding a "name" attribute to each input, instead of querying each field).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by messing around with @Maiya had provided. I took a step back and re-evaluated the javascript and what exactly was going on. Used a submit even listener and had basic form validation on the front end and now I can just ensure on the backend. I ended up using the `e.preventDefault()` right after I stored the form instance in a variable and then checked and submitted or it just shows the errors.

Javascript Changes:

```
let submit = document.getElementById("signupForm")

submit.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
    let form = e.target // get form instance
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(form)
    // error handling
    if (firstNameSubmit == false || lasttNameSubmit  == false || emailSubmit == false || createPasswordSubmit == false || verifyPasswordSubmit == false) {
        console.log('form not done')
    } else { // form completed send to backend!
        form.submit()
    }
```

SignupHandler Changes:

```golang
user := &User{
        fname: r.PostFormValue("fname"),
        lname: r.PostFormValue("lname"),
        email: r.PostFormValue("email"),
        pw:    r.PostFormValue("pass"),
    }
    user.hash = string(helper.HashPassword(user.pw))

    //begin server validation
    if user.fname == "" {
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/signup", http.StatusBadRequest)
        tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "signup.html", nil)
    } else {
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/login", http.StatusOK)
    }
```

Comment: Just as a detail, it is not necessary to put the e.preventDefault() after you assign the e.target to a variable.  The e.preventDefault() is just preventing the default actions that will fire (submitting request and reloading page), but you still have access to the event object after you call e.preventDefault().

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Form method='post'(i.e., instead of using form to make post requests) **just make a post request using axios.** In that way it works even if there is event.preventDefault()